# a value type of "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity type of "System::string^"

Tags: string, winforms, c++-cli, void

I am following a tutorial on youtube for creating forms and I'm getting this error when doing exactly what he is doing. I've searched all over and I cannot figure it out.

here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkhGpWUclc8&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZz6uDid--I09EOImRmPHS0&index=22

below is the code

The part that's in bold is the ONLY part that is throwing an error

String^ strCharName = **openCharDialog1**->InitialDirectory = openCharDialog1->FileName;

```
private: System::Void openButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    Stream^ openCharacter;
    OpenFileDialog^ openCharDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

    if (openCharDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if ((openCharacter = openCharDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
        {

            String^ strCharName = openCharDialog1->InitialDirectory = openCharDialog1->FileName;

            MessageBox::Show(strCharName);

            openCharacter->Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo:

```
String^ strCharName = openCharDialog1->InitialDirectory + openCharDialog1->FileName;
                                                        ^
```

Comment: This is what I get for being up for over 24 hours and dividing "hey I'll just put the finishing touches on my midterm"  also that's the second time I'd done the = instead of +

Comment: @liftedplane it happens, but that's why it's so important to sleep well)